# Ubuntu EasyEngine conditional execution

Tags: cron, ubuntu-18.04, easy-engine

I am using EasyEngine over Ubuntu 18.04.
I must execute `ee cli check-update` in order the know if there is an update.
If there is, I must execute `ee cli update`.

When there is no update, I get

> Success: EasyEngine is at the latest version.

Is there a way I can automate this with CRON? I mean a way to create a CRON to check if there is an update, and in case there is, to update it.

Thanks for any help, as I am a total noob in Linux, CRON, etc

I have tried:

```
ee cron create site_name --command='ee cli update --due-now' --schedule='@every @weekly'
```

It didnt work, returned an error:

> sh: 1: ee: not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, just learned it was a dumb question. Its not possible to schedule for a domain to run a command which should be runned by the host

The correct command, which works is:

```
ee cron create host --command='ee cli update' --schedule='@every @weekly'
```

I hope this helps others